# How to return empty jsx if condition is false using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to render nothing if the condition fails using react.

below is my code,

```
function Parent () {
    const iconRef = React.createRef();
    const iconRect = iconRef && iconRef.getBoundingClientRect();
    return( 
        <button ref={iconRef}/>
        <Child iconRect={iconRect}/>
    );
}


function Child({iconRect}: Props) {
    return (
        {iconRect ? (
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="dialog">
                    //something
                </div>
            </div>
         ) : null}
     );
 }
```

But this doesnt work . it gives error Syntax error unexpected token ,

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: The parent can’t return two elements like that.

Comment: There are **two** problems in that code, one in `Parent` (adjacent elements) and one in `Child` (incorrect use of a JSX expression). The syntax error you describe relates to the `Child`, but both need fixing. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the unwanted curly braces and it would work as expected, thats the reason for the error

```
function Child({iconRect}: Props) {
    return (
        iconRect ? (
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="dialog">
                    //something
                </div>
            </div>
         ) : null
     );
 }
```

Comment: This is indeed the reason for the syntax error the OP reports. (The other answers also provide useful info, but this is the one dealing with the syntax error.)

Comment: As he is already returning null it should work, but the question is a but mis leading

Comment: I don't follow you. I was just saying your answer is correct. While the other answers point out a *different* problem, this is the one that addresses the one the OP asked about.

Comment: What i meant is the error is mentioned at the end of the question but the title is about returning empty jsx

Answer (score 2):

The parent component needs a `React.Fragment`.

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

```
function Parent () {
    const iconRef = React.createRef();
    const iconRect = iconRef && iconRef.getBoundingClientRect();
    return( 
        <React.Fragment>
            <button ref={iconRef}/>
            <Child iconRect={iconRect}/>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: Or in vaguely modern JSX environments, the shorthand form: `<>...</>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just return `null` to render nothing.

Your code doesn't works because there are couple of problems in your code:

- `Parent` component is returning two adjacent elements which is incorrect. You cannot have two adjacent React components next to each other without a common parent element.

  You need to wrap the JSX code returned from the `Parent` component in a wrapper element.

  ```
  return (
     <div>
       <button ref={iconRef}/>
       <Child iconRect={iconRect}/>
     </div>
  );
  ```

  If you don't want to render an extra element, you can use `React.Fragment` component as a wrapper element.

  ```
  return (
     <>
       <button ref={iconRef}/>
       <Child iconRect={iconRect}/>
     </>
  );
  ```
- Curly brackets around the ternary expression, in the `Child` component, are not needed. You only need the curly brackets to wrap the javascript code written between JSX code.

  ```
  return (
    iconRect ? (
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="dialog">
                {/* something */}
            </div>
        </div>
     ) : null
  );
  ```